# Excel - Comparing multiple columns to see if results are identical

Tags: excel-formula

I would like to compare three separate columns in an excel spreadsheet, across thousands of rows.

If any value appears in column A multiple times (say the word hello in column A rows 1 and 4, and the word bye in column A and rows 3 & 5, I would like to check the corresponding values in column B for those rows (ie rows 1&4 and 3&5).

If the values in column B for rows 1&4 are say 15 & 15, and the values for rows 3&5 are 20 & 20 , then I want to check column C.

Now we know rows 1&4 and 3&5 have the same corresponding values in column A & B, I would like to check the corresponding values in column C. If these are different then I would like to perform a specific calculation. If they are the same values in Column C, then I want to ignore these rows.

I am sorry this is very unclear, as I cannot paste an image to show what I mean.  I can email you an example if it helps.

This is way beyond me and my excel skills and I do not know where to start. Any help would be appreciated. I am hoping I don't need to write a Macro.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: unable to understand your question, post an http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

So, to resummarize your question as I understand it:

Column A holds string values (text). There are some duplicates here.

Column B holds number values. When a duplicate occurs in column A, the data in column B may or may not be identical as for the other duplicate entries.

Column C holds values (you did not define what type of values, but I assume these are number values). Sometimes, duplicates in column A hold the same values in column B, and also the same values in column C. In this case, we can ignore the row as all the duplicates agree. Sometimes, duplicates in column A hold different values in column B. In this case, we can also ignore the values. Finally, sometimes duplicates in column A hold the same values in column B, but different values in column C. For these specific values, we want to perform some other type of calculation (which you did not specify).

Put the following in column D, starting at row 2 (assuming a header on row 1), which is the starting point of the formula we will build.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A$1:B1,A2,2,0)=B2,"")
```

This says: Look at column A, starting always at row 1, and going until 1 row above the current row. Check for a match of the text in the current row. If it finds a match there, pull the result from column B. Does that result match column B in the current row? If it matches it will say TRUE; if it doesnt match it will say FALSE. If there are no duplicates yet in column A it will say "".

Now add a new check - if the above formula is TRUE [ie: there is a duplicate in column A, and the result in column B matches], then we want to check the results from column C:

```
=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(A$1:B1,A2,2,0)=B2,VLOOKUP(A$1:C1,A2,3,0)=C2,""),"")
```

This will now return TRUE if the values in column C match for that duplicate in column A (which is only checked if the values in column B match too). Finally, add in your "special calculation", like so:

```
=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(A$1:B1,A2,2,0)=B2,IF(VLOOKUP(A$1:C1,A2,3,0)=C2,"",C2+1),""),"")
```

Where I have C2+1, this is where you will perform your special calculation. This will only be recorded by Excel if: there is a duplicate in column A, that duplicate has a matching value in column B, and that duplicate has an unmatched value in column C.